# How to count duplicate records and, at the same time, be able to print other data in PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following record in my `logtrama` table:

```
id_logtrama    fechaHora    idCliente    idEquipo
    1          2021-04-18       20          8
    2          2021-04-18       20          8
    3          2021-04-18       20          8
    4          2021-04-18       20          1
    5          2021-04-18       4           4
```

And, in my `equipo` table the following:

```
idEquipo    idCliente     tipo
    1          20        Alarm1
    2          1         Alarm2
    3          2         Alarm3
    8          20        Alarm4
```

Now through my query I print results that match the given conditions:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT l.id_logtrama,
                                    l.fechaHora,
                                    l.idCliente,
                                    l.idEquipo,
                                    l.statusGlobal
                                FROM logtrama l
                                INNER JOIN equipo e ON l.idEquipo=e.idEquipo AND l.idCliente=e.idCliente
                                WHERE DATE(fechaHora)=? GROUP BY l.id_logtrama");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date_day);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result(
        $id_logtrama,
        $fechaHora,
        $pag_idCliente,
        $pag_idEquipo,
        $statusGlobal
    );
    
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //print_r(expression)
    }
}
```

In other words, it will print the following result:

```
    1          2021-04-18       20          8
    2          2021-04-18       20          8
    3          2021-04-18       20          8
    4          2021-04-18       20          1
```

Since it is the only data that matches the union of the two tables.

But now what I need is to be able to count the duplicate records in the same query in order to print data, in conclusion I want to achieve the following printing of the last data entered but with its respective count:

```
    ID: 3    Date: 2021-04-18   ID Customer: 20     Id Team: 8   Total repeated records: (3)
    ID: 4    Date: 2021-04-18   ID Customer: 20     ID team: 1   Total repeated records: (1)
```

How can I get that result? Could you explain to me what other conditions I can add to the query, perhaps `COUNT (*)` or `SUM` and how I would have to add this condition to obtain the desired result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but as far as I can tell you don't really need `JOIN` because your `SELECT` fields are all from one table. In the above it does limit the records to ones where there is an associated field in `eqipo` but I'm going to assume that you're just selecting on a per customer basis and thus will add a `WHERE` clause to that effect... If that isn't the case then you can simply add the `INNER JOIN` clause back in and remove the additional `WHERE` clause.

---

What you're attempting to do is aggregate fields together. You can do this in a couple of ways depending on your data and intentions.

From the looks of it all fields will be the same apart from the `id_logtrama` which means we can simply add them into the `GROUP BY` clause of your query:

```
GROUP BY idEquipo, fechaHora, idCliente
```

I'm assuming (from your example) that you want to also `SELECT` the highest `id_logtrama`? To do that we can utilise the `MAX` aggregate function:

```
SELECT MAX(id_logtrama) as id
```

Then of course you need to add in your `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses, leaving you with something like:

```
SELECT MAX(id_logtrama) as id,
    fechaHora as date,
    idCliente as customer,
    idEquipo as team,
    COUNT(*) as count
FROM logtrama
WHERE fechaHora   = ?
    AND idCliente = ?
GROUP BY idEquipo, fechaHora, idCliente
ORDER BY id
```

In code:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT MAX(id_logtrama) as id,
        fechaHora as date,
        idCliente as customer,
        idEquipo as team,
        COUNT(*) as count
    FROM logtrama
    WHERE fechaHora   = ?
        AND idCliente = ?
    GROUP BY idEquipo, fechaHora, idCliente
    ORDER BY id
";

$query = $con->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("si", $date_day, $client_id);
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();

$query->bind_result($id, $date, $customer, $team, $count);

while ($query->fetch()) {
    echo "ID: {$id}, DATE: {$date}, CustomerID: {$customer}, TeamID: {$team}, Total: $count", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Friend but you are not checking that the `idCliente` and the `idEquipo` of the `logtrama` table also match the `idCliente` `idEquipo` of the ` equipo` table the only condition that I can pass is the date , not the `idCliente` or other data, because the data that is registered in the database is through `Arduino` what I need is that when the data sent by `Arduino` is executed then send by I mail that information that I want to print, that's why I can't put the `idCliente`, to the `WHERE`, just send the report every day.

Comment: @Valentina As said above (first paragraph) you can simply add in your original `JOIN` if that's what you need...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id_logtrama 
     , a.fechaHora  
     , a.idCliente 
     , a.idEquipo 
     , b.tipo 
     , c.totals
  FROM logtrama a
  JOIN equipo b
    ON b.idequipo = a.idequipo
   AND b.idCliente = a.idCliente
  JOIN
     ( SELECT MAX(t.id_logtrama) id_logtrama
            , COUNT(*) totals
         FROM logtrama t
         JOIN equipo e
           ON e.idequipo = t.idequipo
          AND e.idCliente = t.idCliente
        GROUP
           BY t.idcliente
            , t.idequipo
     ) c
    ON c.id_logtrama = a.id_logtrama;
```

...or something like that

Comment: ? Isn't that what this says?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see what part of the problem this fails to address.